# How can I find three of the same numbers in a row?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array something like the following.

```
int[][] myArray = 
        {{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1}
         {1, 0, 4, 4, 0, 1}
         {1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 0}
         {2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2}
         {3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0}
         {4, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0}}
```

It would say that one had won because of the 1s in the three 1s in the first column.  Two would not win because they are not in a "row".

I want to do some sort of win checking so that it finds three of the same number in a row, diagonal or column. Sort of like tic-tac-toe but with a larger grid. Before I used a messy set of if statements and goto statements. (It was written in Basic.) I have tried using a system where it found the directions from the last placed piece, in which there is a number of the same, but it didn't work properly. How can I do this in an easy and maintainable way?

Tried code:

```
private static boolean checkBoardCombinations(int[][] board, int inputX, int inputY) {
        int currentPlayer = board[inputX-1][inputY-1];
        boolean[][] directions = new boolean[3][3];
        for(int y = 0; y >= -2; y--){
            for(int x = 0; x >= -2; x--){
                if(inputX+x >= 0 && inputX+x <= 7 && inputY+y >= 0 && inputY+y <= 7 
                        && (board[inputX+x][inputY+y] == currentPlayer)){
                    //System.out.printf("X: %s Y: %s", inputX+x, inputY+y);
                    directions[x+2][y+2] = true;
                }
                else{
                    directions[x+2][y+2] = false;
                }
                //System.out.printf("X: %s Y: %s B: %s,", inputX+x, inputY+y, directions[x+2][y+2]);
            }
            //System.out.println();
        }
        /*
         for(int x = 0; x <= 2; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y <= 2; y++){
                System.out.print(directions[x][y] + " ");
            }
                System.out.println();
        }
        */
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: what logic u applied or paste code will be better

Comment: Do the 3 same values have to be one after another or can they be scattered in the row, diagonal or column?

Comment: What is the range of such numbers? Are they just single digit numbers? Or can they range to any value? Or are they just 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4?

Comment: @NiksTyagi See the code at the bottom. I was thinking of creating a system where it would scan the last placed pieces for the same number. It would store the direction in which the closest number was the same as the last placed piece. From there it would continue to scan in that directions. Finally it would see if there were three trues in a row, column or diagonal.

Comment: @halex The numbers have to be touching, sort of, so yes they have to be one after another.

Comment: @AwfullyAwesome The numbers they could range into would be preset but preferably changeable.

Comment: @Cammy_the_block: Explain it elaborately as to what such range can ever constitute of and whether the size of the array is changeable, as the solution I would suggest will differ based on the situation at hand.

Comment: The range would be from 1 - x. x being a number enter by the user.  x would of course be greater than 1. This would denote the number of players. The array size could also be enter by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the number of players are known, you can iterate over all the players one by one, and check if any player is forming a connection of required length or not.

Such code would look like following:

```
private int[][] grid; // Your array of size ROWS x COLUMNS
private final int ROWS = 6, COLUMNS = 6;
private final int CONSECUTIVE_CONNECTION_REQUIRED = 3;

// Returns true if given playerType is forming a connection, else false.
public boolean checkGrid(int playerType)
{
  // Check downward
  for (int i = 0; i <= ROWS - CONSECUTIVE_CONNECTION_REQUIRED; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
    {
      int counter = 0;
      for (int k = i; k < CONSECUTIVE_CONNECTION_REQUIRED + i; k++)
      {
        if (grid[k][j] == playerType)
          counter++;
      }

      if (counter == CONSECUTIVE_CONNECTION_REQUIRED)
        return true;
    }
  }

  // Check across
  for (int i = 0; i <= COLUMNS - CONSECUTIVE_CONNECTION_REQUIRED; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++)
    {
      int counter = 0;
      for (int k = i; k < CONSECUTIVE_CONNECTION_REQUIRED + i; k++)
      {
        if (grid[j][k] == playerType)
          counter++;
      }

      if (counter == CONSECUTIVE_CONNECTION_REQUIRED)
        return true;
    }
  }

  // Check left to right diagonally
  for (int i = 0; i <= ROWS - CONSECUTIVE_CONNECTION_REQUIRED; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j <= COLUMNS - CONSECUTIVE_CONNECTION_REQUIRED; j++)
    {
      int counter = 0;
      for (int k = i, m = j; k < CONSECUTIVE_CONNECTION_REQUIRED + i; k++, m++)
      {
        if (grid[k][m] == playerType)
          counter++;
      }

      if (counter == CONSECUTIVE_CONNECTION_REQUIRED)
        return true;
    }
  }

  // Check right to left diagonally
  for (int i = 0; i <= ROWS - CONSECUTIVE_CONNECTION_REQUIRED; i++)
  {
    for (int j = COLUMNS - 1; j >= COLUMNS - CONSECUTIVE_CONNECTION_REQUIRED; j--)
    {
      int counter = 0;
      for (int k = i, m = j; k < CONSECUTIVE_CONNECTION_REQUIRED + i; k++, m--)
      {
        if (grid[k][m] == playerType)
          counter++;
      }

      if (counter == CONSECUTIVE_CONNECTION_REQUIRED)
        return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Where playerType is 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on...

You can use `checkGrid()` method like following:

```
for(int i = MIN_PLAYER_NUMBER; i <= MAX_PLAYER_NUMBER; i++)
{
  if(checkGrid(i))
  {
    // Player i is forming the connection!!!
  }
}
```

But if you don't want to iterate over your grid this many times, then drop your two dimensional array, and use a graph with adjacency list representation. Write a proper API for that which lets you make changes in your particular representation easily, and you can then find if any player is making a connection of particular length in the graph or not, in less iterations.

Comment: What is a graph with adjacency list representation?

Comment: @Cammy_the_block: Its a data structure. Just like arrays, lists, maps, sets, trees, there are graphs. Graphs can be represented in many ways, and one such type of representation is by using adjacency list. Search on internet to know more about it.

Answer (score 1):

Although you already accepted an answer I thought to also submit you my answer for diversity :)

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int[][] myArray = 
    {{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1},
     {1, 0, 4, 4, 0, 1},
     {1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 0},
     {2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2},
     {3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0},
     {4, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0}};
     System.out.println(testForWinner(myArray));
}

/**
 * Returns -1 if no winner
 */
static int testForWinner(int[][] ar) {
    for(int i=0; i<ar.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<ar[i].length; j++) {
            if(checkNext(ar, i, j, 0, 1, 1)) { //Check the element in the next column
                return ar[i][j];
            }
            for(int k=-1; k<=1; k++) { //Check the three adjacent elements in the next row
                if(checkNext(ar, i, j, 1, k, 1)) {
                    return ar[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

/**
 * Step number `step` starting at `ar[i][j]` in direction `(di, dj)`.
 * If we made 3 steps we have a winner
 */
static boolean checkNext(int[][] ar, int i, int j, int di, int dj, int step) {
    if(step==3) {
        return true;
    }
    if(i+di<0 || i+di>ar.length-1 || j+dj<0 || j+dj>ar[i].length-1) {
        return false;
    }
    if(ar[i+di][j+dj]==ar[i][j]) {
        return checkNext(ar, i+di, j+dj, di, dj, step+1);
    }
    return false;
}
```

See it in action: http://ideone.com/Ou2sRh

Comment: I don't understand the whole step thing. You always do checkNext with step being one. Also your solution is too confusing for me. :P

Comment: @Cammy_the_block Inside `checkNext` I call the method recursively with `step+1`. This way I walk along a direction until I took 3 steps along 3 equal values. My goal was to use recursion for my solution :)